# Moq Xunit tests work locally but not AzureDevops

Tags: c#, testing, azure-devops, moq, func

```
var mock = new Mock<IMyClass>(); 

mock.SetupSequence(x => x.MyMethod()).Returns(0).Returns(1).Returns(2). 

Func<IMyClass> func = () => mock.Object);
```

I tried to mock object in `Func<mock.Object>` using `SetupSequence`, `Queue` or `Callback`.

In further methods, my Func is invoked and then MyMethod of interface is executed.
It works locally well however AzureDevops seems to take only last Returns(2).
Azure devops doesn't treat it as sequence.
I have loop in my program and I need multiple results. Due to this issue assertion doesn't work.
Azure devops seems to not recognize mock method.
I have many working test based on moq, but this one is so tricky.

Please help.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducable example (the rest of the test) and any other info from devops (assuming it's just failing, but the stack trace might have a clue)

Comment: @rgvlee I checked logs, they are not meaningful. It is written in logs that assertion is false. I append list and it should be 3 elements but there is only one. Real example would be hard for me to provide. It's big blocker for me now, I can agree for any workarounds. I changed assertion to verify invocation of MyMethod. It was Verified by moq only ones but it should be 3 times. Azure Devops doesn't  see Returns(0) and Returns(1)